# How do you filter a measure in MDX and output only a single row for the measure?

Tags: filter, mdx, olap

Given the MDX:

```
select {[Measures].[Effort], [Measures].[Count]} on columns from [Tickets]
```

.. How can zero (0) values for `[Measures].[Effort]` be filtered out from the `[Measures].[Count]` so that the resulting `[Measures].[Count]` value is reduced by the number of "Tickets" with zero (0) effort?

One would think that it would be easy to filter out values, however that's not the case.  The following does not reduce the count of course because the final, single value output is naturally greater than zero (0):

```
select {[Measures].[Effort], FILTER([Measures].[Count], [Measures].[Effort] > 0 )} on 0 
from [Tickets]
```

.. Also, please assume millions of tickets so placing a ticket ID on axis 1 and then filtering and then summing after the MDX result is returned would not be performant

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is a matter and the following query is too slow:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[RealCount] as
SUM(
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Effort] > 0,
        [Measures].[Count],
        Null
    )
)

Select 
{[Measures].[Effort],[Measures].[Count],[Measures].[RealCount]} on 0
From [Tickets]
```

You have to filter it out on the DWH to pre-calculate a real count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your ticket hierarchy structure so will guess that bit but I would imagine something along these lines:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[RealCount] AS 
 SUM(
   [Ticket].[Ticket].[Ticket Id], 
   Iif(
     [Measures].[Effort] > 0
    ,1
    ,NULL
   )
 )
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[Effort]
   ,[Measures].[Count]
   ,[Measures].[RealCount]
  } on 0
FROM [Tickets];
```

If the above gives the correct result then it can be further improved by moving some of the logic to the `cube script` - this bit:

```
CREATE HIDDEN SumTicker;
[Measures].[SumTicker] = Iif([Measures].[Effort]  > 0,1,NULL);
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR([Measures].[SumTicker]) = [Measures].[Effort];
```

Then the script becomes:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[RealCount] AS 
 SUM(
   [Ticket].[Ticket].[Ticket Id], 
   [Measures].[SumTicker]
 )
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[Effort]
   ,[Measures].[Count]
   ,[Measures].[RealCount]
  } on 0
FROM [Tickets];
```